# The labels of a slider don't show

Tags: java, swing, jslider

This problem is driving me crazy!

When I use `setLabelTable` and `setPaintLabels` to display the label of a `JSlider`, the slider is no longer displayed and blows up the layout.

Can you help me?

This is the code of my class `sliderPlayer`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class sliderPlayer extends JPanel
{
static final int MIN = 2;
static final int MAX = 300;
static final int INIT = 15;   

// constructor
public sliderPlayer() 
    {
    super(new GridLayout(1,1));
    JSlider slid = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,MIN,MAX,INIT);
    slid.setMajorTickSpacing(MAX/5);
    slid.setMinorTickSpacing(MAX/10);
    slid.setPaintTicks(true);
    slid.setLabelTable(slid.createStandardLabels(10));
    slid.setPaintLabels(true);
    add(slid);
    }       
}
```

If I remove the following lines it works well but, of course, it does not draw the label!

```
slid.setLabelTable(slid.createStandardLabels(10));
slid.setPaintLabels(true);
```

This is the code that uses the slider:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Finestra extends JFrame
{
public static  int LARGHEZZA;
public static  int ALTEZZA ;
public GridLayout mainLayout;
public JPanel tavolo;
public JPanel panelSlidePlayer;
public Finestra()
    {
    super("il D I L E M M A del PRIGIONIERO");
    this.setVisible(true);

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int W=(int)screenSize.getWidth();
    int H=(int)screenSize.getHeight();
    LARGHEZZA=W-W/5;
    ALTEZZA=H-H/5;
    Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(W/10, H/10,LARGHEZZA, ALTEZZA);
    this.setBounds(rect);
    mainLayout= new GridLayout(1,1); // Layout principale
    this.setLayout(mainLayout);
    tavolo= new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));

    getContentPane().add(tavolo);
    getContentPane().add(new sliderPlayer());

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact question? Could you give us some more details what you mean by "blow up" ?

Comment: Sure. I use a gridLayout with a row and two columns. In the first column I put a panel and in the second column I want to put the slider. If I put it without a label everything works fine but if I want to display the slider's label strange things happen: sometimes the layout is empty, other times all the space is occupied by the first panel!

Comment: (I added in my post the code that generates the layout and uses the slider)

Comment: OK: after tests, attempts, research I solved the problem!

Comment: @paolo marongiu, please tell me how did you fix it?

Comment: Very willingly @John !  I have deleted the instructions:           Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(W/10, H/10,LARGHEZZA, ALTEZZA);    this.setBounds(rect);    in the class Finestra.  I replaced them with this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(LARGHEZZA,ALTEZZA)); and i added, in the end: this.pack();

Comment: You might want to convert this to an answer, just so it's easier for other to find the solution. Welcome to StackOverflow btw

Comment: I took your advice,  @monamona .Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After tests, attempts, research I solved the problem! 
 I have deleted the instructions:

```
Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(W/10, H/10,LARGHEZZA, ALTEZZA); 
this.setBounds(rect);
```

in the class Finestra. I replaced them with:

```
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(LARGHEZZA,ALTEZZA));
```

and i added, in the end:

```
this.pack();
```